Visual studio 10 fails to build a test example (32bit) of boost regex (1.47): link error 1104
Boost provides a test example (linked to boost_regex):
// test.cpp
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    boost::regex pat( "^Subject: (Re: |Aw: )*(.*)" );

    while (std::cin)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        boost::smatch matches;
        if (boost::regex_match(line, matches, pat))
            std::cout << matches[2] << std::endl;
    }
}

My own CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(test)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

set(BOOST_ROOT "D:/test/boost_1_47_0")
set(BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS "${BOOST_ROOT}")
set(BOOST_LIBRARY_DIRS "${BOOST_ROOT}/stage/lib")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES (${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES( ${BOOST_LIBRARY_DIRS} )

set(testlib_src test.cpp)
add_library(testlib SHARED ${testlib_src})

target_link_libraries(testlib boost_regex-vc100-mt-1_47)

Build (32 bit)

Source Path:

cwd: D:\test\test\test.cpp
 D:\test\test\CMakeList.txt

 D:\test\test\build


Boost Path:

D:\test\boost_1_47_0\
Built by
bootstrap.bat

.\b2 --build-type=complete variant=release link=shared runtime-link=shared stage


Os: win10

Configure: cmake 3.24 + vs 2010 + nmake
cd build

cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 10" -G "NMake Makefiles"

nmake


Error:

fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_regex-vc100-mt-1_47.lib'

Fix

A file named boost_regex-vc100-mt-1_47.lib exists in the stage/lib directory but without the lib prefix.
Is the missing lib prefix causing the link error?
Moreover, I tried both 64-bit and 32-bit builds, and both failed.

Google cmake library prefix

Since Boost is not configured by CMake, can I change its naming convention? Using b2 or something else? I have tried Boost on Linux before, and everything is fine. But for Windows, I found that CMake behaves differently with the lib prefix and suffix.

I have no idea and would not recommend doing that anyway. On Windows, library names generally don't start with lib.

Any specific reasons you want to build a boost from thirteen years ago?

Yeah, I need to benchmark my case using an academic code that is built on a very old toolchain. Currently, I have no other good options.

@Botje presumably because they're using a compiler from 14 years ago

The lib prefix is used for static libraries, you've only built the shared ones https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming. You need to define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK to swtich the automatic linking to use shared libraries.
You should use https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html and link to the generated targets which is both simpler and more reliable than manually specifying the includes and libraries:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(test)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

set(BOOST_ROOT "D:/test/boost_1_47_0")
find_package(Boost 1.47 REQUIRED COMPONENTS
             regex)
set(testlib_src test.cpp)
add_library(testlib SHARED ${testlib_src})

target_link_libraries(testlib Boost::regex)


Hello there! As you noted, the missing lib prefix of my previous boost indicates a dynamic build. Does it mean the CMake or Visual Studio 2010 default link is static instead of dynamic? That is why my lib could not find a dependency. I just changed the boost build setting to link=static,shared and found the files boost_xxx.dll and libboost_xxx.lib, which fits your comment.

Nothing to do with cmake or visual studio, it's boosts autolinking that defaults to static libraries. If you use cmake correctly it'll set everything up for you automatically
